# How to solve "as defined by 'HeadersPath' in its `Info.plist` file" problem in Swift, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I added 'SwiftGit3' library in my Swift Project.

And I got the following error when building the iOS app.

Yesterday, I added 'SwiftGit2' library in same Swift Project.

It runs very well.

But I don't know Why 'SwiftGit2' is run well and 'SwiftGit3' is not working.

```
Showing Recent Messages
Missing path (/Users/hyeminchoi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clonet-clzjmptbegybokczysumrjbmhcdx/SourcePackages/checkouts/SwiftGit3/External/Clibgit2.xcframework/ios-x86_64-simulator/Headers) from XCFramework 'Clibgit2.xcframework' as defined by 'HeadersPath' in its `Info.plist` file
```

Here is 'vi Info.plist'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>AvailableLibraries</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>HeadersPath</key>
                        <string>Headers</string>
                        <key>LibraryIdentifier</key>
                        <string>ios-x86_64-simulator</string>
                        <key>LibraryPath</key>
                        <string>libgit2.a</string>
                        <key>SupportedArchitectures</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>x86_64</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>SupportedPlatform</key>
                        <string>ios</string>
                        <key>SupportedPlatformVariant</key>
                        <string>simulator</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                        <key>HeadersPath</key>
                        <string>Headers</string>
                        <key>LibraryIdentifier</key>
                        <string>macos-arm64</string>
                        <key>LibraryPath</key>
                        <string>libgit2.a</string>
                        <key>SupportedArchitectures</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>arm64</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>SupportedPlatform</key>
                        <string>macos</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                        <key>HeadersPath</key>
                        <string>Headers</string>
                        <key>LibraryIdentifier</key>
                        <string>ios-arm64</string>
                        <key>LibraryPath</key>
                        <string>libgit2.a</string>
                        <key>SupportedArchitectures</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>arm64</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>SupportedPlatform</key>
                        <string>ios</string>
                </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>XFWK</string>
        <key>XCFrameworkFormatVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone who knows a solution, please reply.
thanks.

Comment: Same question. Any progress?